# Java Error when running application: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x22ba606d, pid=14888, tid=10716

Tags: java

Everytime I am running the application this is the outcome of it? Any idea what it might be causing the problem? I reinstalled java like 5 times.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x22ba606d, pid=14888, tid=10716
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x22ba606d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x22343400):  JavaThread "Thread-20" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10716, stack(0x24290000,0x24490000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0xf4f69ce2

Registers:
EAX=0xf4f69ce2, EBX=0x00010000, ECX=0x2448ed58, EDX=0x644c131b
ESP=0x2448ed48, EBP=0x2448ed58, ESI=0x252328a8, EDI=0x6d0b0440
EIP=0x22ba606d, EFLAGS=0x00010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x2448ed48)
0x2448ed48:   f4f69ce2 00000000 00000001 00320aba
0x2448ed58:   2448ed64 6450ed3b 644c131c 2448edd8
0x2448ed68:   644b95bd 644c131c 37a8276e 22343400
0x2448ed78:   250ea7f8 250ea7f8 00010004 65191064
0x2448ed88:   6519105e 65191058 65191052 6519104c
0x2448ed98:   00eeb450 aaaaab36 22343400 2448edcc
0x2448eda8:   5b40f7a0 22343400 00000006 00000008
0x2448edb8:   22343400 00320aba 250ea7f8 252328a8 

Instructions: (pc=0x22ba606d)
0x22ba604d:   00 00 00 d2 ae a9 7f 00 1c 00 8b 8b ff 55 8b ec
0x22ba605d:   83 ec 0c a1 64 90 14 6d 33 c5 89 e9 e3 a3 50 4a
0x22ba606d:   00 00 00 d6 ae a5 7f 00 1d 00 8b 64 a1 18 00 00
0x22ba607d:   00 ff a0 0c 0a 00 00 8d 64 24 00 e9 33 a8 57 4a 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0xf4f69ce2 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00010000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x2448ed58 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x22343400
EDX=0x644c131b is an unknown value
ESP=0x2448ed48 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x22343400
EBP=0x2448ed58 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x22343400
ESI=0x252328a8 is an unknown value
EDI=0x6d0b0440 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x24290000,0x24490000],  sp=0x2448ed48,  free space=2043k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x22ba606d
C  [togl_31c151da5.dll+0xed3b]
C  [jaggl.dll+0x95bd]
j  jaggl.OpenGL.init(Ljava/awt/Canvas;IIIIII)J+0
j  aev.<init>(Ljava/awt/Canvas;Lde;Lew;Lmx;Lmy;Lmh;I)V+689
j  co.h(Ljava/awt/Canvas;Lde;Lew;Lmx;Lmy;Lmh;I)Ldf;+14
j  df.i(ILjava/awt/Canvas;Lde;Lew;Lmx;Lmy;Lmh;Lpj;IIII)Ldf;+41
j  v.h(ILjava/awt/Canvas;Lde;Lew;Lmx;Lmy;Lmh;Lpj;II)Ldf;+51
j  yc.fa(ILjava/lang/String;ZI)V+300
j  tb.fk(ILjava/lang/String;ZI)V+23
j  me.fr(IZI)V+16
j  au.p(I)I+3373
j  wt.v(I)V+53
j  client.ah(B)V+826
j  rq.x(B)V+93
j  rq.q(I)V+375
j  rq.run()V+4
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x158985]
V  [jvm.dll+0x21df3e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x158a1e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x158ba6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x158c17]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfd45f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17bddc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17beca]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1c0466]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c556]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c600]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x13744]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5a064]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5a02f]
C  0x00000000

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  jaggl.OpenGL.init(Ljava/awt/Canvas;IIIIII)J+0
j  aev.<init>(Ljava/awt/Canvas;Lde;Lew;Lmx;Lmy;Lmh;I)V+689
j  co.h(Ljava/awt/Canvas;Lde;Lew;Lmx;Lmy;Lmh;I)Ldf;+14
j  df.i(ILjava/awt/Canvas;Lde;Lew;Lmx;Lmy;Lmh;Lpj;IIII)Ldf;+41
j  v.h(ILjava/awt/Canvas;Lde;Lew;Lmx;Lmy;Lmh;Lpj;II)Ldf;+51
j  yc.fa(ILjava/lang/String;ZI)V+300
j  tb.fk(ILjava/lang/String;ZI)V+23
j  me.fr(IZI)V+16
j  au.p(I)I+3373
j  wt.v(I)V+53
j  client.ah(B)V+826
j  rq.x(B)V+93
j  rq.q(I)V+375
j  rq.run()V+4
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x22342000 JavaThread "Thread-37" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=18688, stack(0x27540000,0x27740000)]
  0x1eccf400 JavaThread "Thread-36" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15368, stack(0x271c0000,0x273c0000)]
  0x1eccf000 JavaThread "Thread-35" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6448, stack(0x26f80000,0x27180000)]
  0x1ecd1c00 JavaThread "Java Sound Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19124, stack(0x25bd0000,0x25dd0000)]
  0x1ecd1000 JavaThread "Thread-33" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16344, stack(0x26510000,0x26710000)]
  0x2233e400 JavaThread "Thread-32" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8676, stack(0x262d0000,0x264d0000)]
  0x2233d800 JavaThread "Thread-31" [_thread_blocked, id=15208, stack(0x26090000,0x26290000)]
  0x22343000 JavaThread "Thread-30" [_thread_blocked, id=18516, stack(0x25e50000,0x26050000)]
  0x2233dc00 JavaThread "TRiBot Paintable Display Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=19052, stack(0x259d0000,0x25bd0000)]
  0x22340800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=10952, stack(0x25310000,0x25510000)]
  0x2233f400 JavaThread "Thread-27" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1360, stack(0x24e90000,0x25090000)]
  0x22340400 JavaThread "Thread-26" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12948, stack(0x23c90000,0x23e90000)]
  0x2233c800 JavaThread "TRiBot Cache Handler" [_thread_blocked, id=7152, stack(0x24c50000,0x24e50000)]
  0x22344000 JavaThread "TRiBot Mouse Movement Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=13588, stack(0x24a10000,0x24c10000)]
  0x2233e800 JavaThread "Thread-24" [_thread_blocked, id=1980, stack(0x247d0000,0x249d0000)]
  0x22342800 JavaThread "Thread-23" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14672, stack(0x24490000,0x24690000)]
=>0x22343400 JavaThread "Thread-20" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10716, stack(0x24290000,0x24490000)]
  0x2233d000 JavaThread "Thread-19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14940, stack(0x24090000,0x24290000)]
  0x22341000 JavaThread "Thread-18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4880, stack(0x23e90000,0x24090000)]
  0x2233f000 JavaThread "Thread-17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18884, stack(0x21e00000,0x22000000)]
  0x1ecd2800 JavaThread "Thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=19244, stack(0x23170000,0x23370000)]
  0x1ecd0000 JavaThread "Project Emperor Goose Init Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=14792, stack(0x22f30000,0x23130000)]
  0x1ecd2000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9260, stack(0x228f0000,0x22af0000)]
  0x1ecd0800 JavaThread "Event Cleaner Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=8576, stack(0x21bc0000,0x21dc0000)]
  0x1ecd1400 JavaThread "Thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=10892, stack(0x20750000,0x20950000)]
  0x1eccfc00 JavaThread "Timer-1" [_thread_blocked, id=15176, stack(0x21980000,0x21b80000)]
  0x1ecce800 JavaThread "Timer-0" [_thread_blocked, id=18696, stack(0x21740000,0x21940000)]
  0x1ecce400 JavaThread "TRiBot Garbage Collection Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=9364, stack(0x21500000,0x21700000)]
  0x1ec3ec00 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=14752, stack(0x20dc0000,0x20fc0000)]
  0x00eed000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=17404, stack(0x00f90000,0x01190000)]
  0x1eb44000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2628, stack(0x209c0000,0x20bc0000)]
  0x1ea91c00 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=7600, stack(0x1ff00000,0x20100000)]
  0x1ea2b800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12852, stack(0x1f370000,0x1f570000)]
  0x1ea29000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=14088, stack(0x1f120000,0x1f320000)]
  0x1ea28c00 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6268, stack(0x1eee0000,0x1f0e0000)]
  0x1d8dbc00 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7932, stack(0x1e730000,0x1e930000)]
  0x1d8b1400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18224, stack(0x1e6a0000,0x1e6f0000)]
  0x1d8af800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13756, stack(0x1e460000,0x1e660000)]
  0x1d8ae800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4276, stack(0x1e220000,0x1e420000)]
  0x1d8ae000 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13048, stack(0x1dfe0000,0x1e1e0000)]
  0x1d893c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18428, stack(0x1dcc0000,0x1dec0000)]
  0x1d88b800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12200, stack(0x1da80000,0x1dc80000)]

Other Threads:
  0x1d889c00 VMThread [stack: 0x1d9f0000,0x1da40000] [id=17596]
  0x1d8e7400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x1e970000,0x1e9c0000] [id=13044]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 par new generation   total 60672K, used 2478K [0x04800000, 0x089d0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 53952K,   4% used [0x04800000, 0x04a6b890, 0x07cb0000)
  from space 6720K,   0% used [0x07cb0000, 0x07cb0000, 0x08340000)
  to   space 6720K,   0% used [0x08340000, 0x08340000, 0x089d0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 67824K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 20803K, capacity 21094K, committed 21248K, reserved 21888K

Card table byte_map: [0x04730000,0x04800000] byte_map_base: 0x0470c000

Marking Bits: (CMSBitMap*) 0x00e12c88
 Bits: [0x1ca90000, 0x1d29b000)

Mod Union Table: (CMSBitMap*) 0x00e12ce8
 Bits: [0x01190000, 0x011a0160)

Polling page: 0x00980000

CodeCache: size=32768Kb used=4008Kb max_used=4008Kb free=28759Kb
 bounds [0x02600000, 0x029f0000, 0x04600000]
 total_blobs=1925 nmethods=1591 adapters=263
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 14.698 Thread 0x1d8b1400 1601   !         zu::e (86 bytes)
Event: 14.699 Thread 0x1d8b1400 nmethod 1601 0x029e0548 code [0x029e06a0, 0x029e09fc]
Event: 14.705 Thread 0x1d8b1400 1602   !         sj::g (603 bytes)
Event: 14.709 Thread 0x1d8b1400 nmethod 1602 0x029e0f08 code [0x029e1330, 0x029e2158]
Event: 14.715 Thread 0x1d8b1400 1604             aoi::r (2957 bytes)
Event: 14.797 Thread 0x1d8b1400 nmethod 1604 0x029e2e08 code [0x029e30b0, 0x029e4e1c]
Event: 14.797 Thread 0x1d8b1400 1605   !         ny::fm (271 bytes)
Event: 14.798 Thread 0x1d8b1400 nmethod 1605 0x029e8448 code [0x029e8690, 0x029e8e74]
Event: 14.799 Thread 0x1d8b1400 1606             java.io.File::<init> (113 bytes)
Event: 14.800 Thread 0x1d8b1400 nmethod 1606 0x029e9ac8 code [0x029e9c60, 0x029ea024]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 11.882 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=50 (full 20):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 20505K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K,  98% used [0x04800000, 0x059c6668, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000, 0x05ea0000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05a20000, 0x05a20000, 0x05c60000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 74928K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 18920K, capacity 19200K, committed 19328K, reserved 19840K
Event: 11.887 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=51 (full 20):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 2304K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K,   0% used [0x04800000, 0x04800000, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05a20000, 0x05c60000, 0x05c60000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05c60000, 0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 93037K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 18920K, capacity 19200K, committed 19328K, reserved 19840K
}
Event: 14.140 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=51 (full 21):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 20864K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K, 100% used [0x04800000, 0x05a20000, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05a20000, 0x05c60000, 0x05c60000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05c60000, 0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 93037K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 19566K, capacity 19844K, committed 20096K, reserved 20864K
Event: 14.143 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=52 (full 21):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 2304K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K,   0% used [0x04800000, 0x04800000, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000, 0x05ea0000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05a20000, 0x05a20000, 0x05c60000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 99279K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 19566K, capacity 19844K, committed 20096K, reserved 20864K
}
Event: 14.538 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=52 (full 21):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 20864K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K, 100% used [0x04800000, 0x05a20000, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000, 0x05ea0000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05a20000, 0x05a20000, 0x05c60000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 99279K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 19568K, capacity 19844K, committed 20096K, reserved 20864K
Event: 14.540 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=53 (full 21):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 2304K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K,   0% used [0x04800000, 0x04800000, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05a20000, 0x05c60000, 0x05c60000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05c60000, 0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 101278K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 19568K, capacity 19844K, committed 20096K, reserved 20864K
}
Event: 14.705 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=53 (full 21):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 19878K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K,  94% used [0x04800000, 0x05929898, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05a20000, 0x05c60000, 0x05c60000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05c60000, 0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 75243K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 20311K, capacity 20582K, committed 20736K, reserved 20864K
Event: 14.708 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=54 (full 21):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 2304K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K,   0% used [0x04800000, 0x04800000, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000, 0x05ea0000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05a20000, 0x05a20000, 0x05c60000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 78961K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 20311K, capacity 20582K, committed 20736K, reserved 20864K
}
Event: 14.716 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=54 (full 21):
 par new generation   total 20864K, used 4135K [0x04800000, 0x05ea0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 18560K,   9% used [0x04800000, 0x049c9cc8, 0x05a20000)
  from space 2304K, 100% used [0x05c60000, 0x05ea0000, 0x05ea0000)
  to   space 2304K,   0% used [0x05a20000, 0x05a20000, 0x05c60000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 78961K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 20322K, capacity 20614K, committed 20864K, reserved 20864K
Event: 14.795 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=55 (full 22):
 par new generation   total 60672K, used 0K [0x04800000, 0x089d0000, 0x0c8a0000)
  eden space 53952K,   0% used [0x04800000, 0x04800000, 0x07cb0000)
  from space 6720K,   0% used [0x07cb0000, 0x07cb0000, 0x08340000)
  to   space 6720K,   0% used [0x08340000, 0x08340000, 0x089d0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 134588K, used 67824K [0x0c8a0000, 0x14c0f000, 0x1ca00000)
 Metaspace       used 20322K, capacity 20614K, committed 20864K, reserved 20864K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
```

Hope you can figure it out.

Comment: Probably provide some code, and your JVM version. Otherwise, not much to start from here.

Answer (score 2):

JVM is crashed by external native libs, so its reinstall is wasting time. As you can see, problematic frame (C 0x22ba606d) contains:

```
    C  0x22ba606d
    C  [togl_31c151da5.dll+0xed3b]
    C  [jaggl.dll+0x95bd]
    j  jaggl.OpenGL.init(Ljava/awt/Canvas;IIIIII)J+0
```

This means that togl_31c151da5.dll tries to call nonexistent native function. Usually this means that native library binding have diverged versions.

Maybe jaggl maintainers can help you (I guess, they are called Jagex and you are trying to start one of their games).

Answer (score -2):

I've had this issue a few times and more often then not, faulty RAM was to blame. You can memtest (http://www.memtest86.com/) to check your RAM.